# Pandas join/concat operation in one to join dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have 3 dataframes that look like the following:

```
>>> a
                     val1
2018-03-04 12:40:00     1
2018-03-04 12:40:01     2
2018-03-04 12:40:02     3
>>> b
                     val2
2018-03-04 12:40:00     5
2018-03-04 12:40:01     2
2018-03-04 12:40:02     1
>>> c
                     val2
2018-03-04 12:40:03    -3
2018-03-04 12:40:04     2
2018-03-04 12:40:05     6
```

I would like to "join and concat" them into 1 dataframe that looks like the following:

```
>>> df
                     val1  val2
2018-03-04 12:40:00     1     5
2018-03-04 12:40:01     2     2
2018-03-04 12:40:02     3     1
2018-03-04 12:40:03   NaN    -3
2018-03-04 12:40:04   NaN     2
2018-03-04 12:40:05   NaN     6
```

So that any values at a similar index get merged, and those at an index that doesn't currently exist are just appended at that index.

Using `join` doesn't work:

```
>>> a.join(c)
                     val1  val2
2018-03-04 12:40:00     1   NaN
2018-03-04 12:40:01     2   NaN
2018-03-04 12:40:02     3   NaN
```

Using `concat` in combination with `join` still doesn't work, and just goes to show that `join` wouldn't achieve the job anyway, as instead of replacing the `NaN`'s, it creates another column

```
>>> pd.concat([a,c]).join(b, lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y')
                     val1  val2_x  val2_y
2018-03-04 12:40:00   1.0     NaN     5.0
2018-03-04 12:40:01   2.0     NaN     2.0
2018-03-04 12:40:02   3.0     NaN     1.0
2018-03-04 12:40:03   NaN    -3.0     NaN
2018-03-04 12:40:04   NaN     2.0     NaN
2018-03-04 12:40:05   NaN     6.0     NaN
```

But even so, in my case, there is no way to tell which dataframe contains indices that do not lie within the other dataframes, and which has similar indices to another dataframe, so the solution would need to be general.

I am capable of doing this in python, but I wanted to know if there was a pandas solution first, as pandas is more efficient and faster.

Comment: can you try `df= pd.concat([a,c])` and then `df.update(b)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
df=pd.concat([a,b,c],sort=False)
df.groupby(df.index).first()
```

Or:

```
pd.concat([a,b,c],sort=True).max(level=0)
```

Or if there are just these 3 dfs, you can also try `combine_first`:

```
a.combine_first(b).combine_first(c)
```

---

```
                     val1  val2
2018-03-04 12:40:00   1.0   5.0
2018-03-04 12:40:01   2.0   2.0
2018-03-04 12:40:02   3.0   1.0
2018-03-04 12:40:03   NaN  -3.0
2018-03-04 12:40:04   NaN   2.0
2018-03-04 12:40:05   NaN   6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df= pd.concat([a,c]) 
df.update(b)
```

**Output**

```
                     val1  val2
2018-03-04 12:40:00   1.0   5.0
2018-03-04 12:40:01   2.0   2.0
2018-03-04 12:40:02   3.0   1.0
2018-03-04 12:40:03   NaN  -3.0
2018-03-04 12:40:04   NaN   2.0
2018-03-04 12:40:05   NaN   6.0
```